# Why are there no other intelligent aliens in the 2004 Battlestar Galactica universe?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Why are there no other intelligent aliens in the Battlestar Galactica universe?

Comment: Not all fictional universes have non-human intelligences. *Dune* and *Foundation* spring to mind.

Comment: @james sheridan when they land on the New Caprica there are no alien life except plants ?

Comment: The fact that a planet supports life does not mean that there will be intelligent life present.

Comment: @phantom42 I know but we don't see even any insects , I guess due to evolution we might could even see different kind of plants ?

Comment: Let me rephrase: why _would_ there be intelligent aliens?

Comment: I think the more interesting question is why there is no animal life at all, then, instead of intelligent aliens.

Comment: SPOILER: There is animal life on new Earth, in fact they talk about incorporating with the indigenous tribal human population. Not alien, but also not "no animal life at all."

Comment: I like to think of it as The [Firefly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_%28TV_series%29) Effect. You watch a rip-roaring space adventure without it being obvious there aren't aliens until either A) after the fact or B) a light-bulb moment.

Comment: They play with the same trope in Red Dwarf. Humanity has colonised the galaxy but Rimmer is convinced he'll meet an alien.

Comment: I think it's enough to say, because that's not what the story is about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Co-producer and writer David Weedle [says](http://www.airlockalpha.com/node/2356/hemlock-grove-returns-to-netflix.html):

> Rubber-headed humanoid aliens have always had a place in sci-fi and always will have a place. I'm sure others will find inventive and revealing ways to utilize them. But because of Star Trek and shows of that ilk, they have become a cliche and we have challenged ourselves to create a compelling drama without have to resort to lizard men from deep space.

Also, Edward James Olmos, playing William Adama, was very reluctant to accept sci-fi clichés (including rubber-headed humanoids), so much so [he jokingly threatened](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2010/10/galactica-technobabble/):

> The first four-eyed monster I see, I’m going to faint on camera, and you’re going to write me off the show.

The series is about humans, about being human. Intelligences other than human or cylon would seriously dilute the show's message. Also note that BSG is not the only space opera without alien intelligence: Firefly springs to mind.

---

Oh and, in your comments you wonder how is it possible to have complex plant life and no animal life whatsoever on New Caprica: yeah, well, personally I always thought they showed the plants on New Caprica and the Algae Planet as way too complex organisms. It's a bit of a bad science in the show (bad science peaked around the Algae Planet arc, the "star cluster" part was painful to watch), due to budget constraints and undereducated set designers.

Comment: +1 For the informative comment by the producers. But I'm puzzled... you were surprised by the bad science of showing plant life with no animal life in a show with miracles and angelic beings? :P (I love the reimagined BSG, but the religion-come-true aspects were painful to me, especially as they grew more important in the series, and atheist characters either recanted or were shown to be in the wrong; the strongest atheist being the main villain of the show :( )

Comment: @AndresF. "surprised" may be too strong a word: it's just that there was a whole lot of really silly stuff in season 3 that featured all the stuff I disliked in any Star Treks ("star cluster", gosh, that really did it to me), and which was in stark constrast with the relatively technobabble-free beginnings. But it's ultimately a matter of taste. Personally, I loved the religious aspect, and I don't regard it as bad science at all because it doesn't pretend to be scientific. Then again, I grew up reading Philip Dick, so no wonder I liked the miracle stuff :p

Comment: I love Phil Dick as well! And indeed religion (and in general "the psychology of the soul") are his themes. But in BSG I expected more SF, especially since -- as you say -- the series beginning was relatively technobabble-free (and even babble-free in general). The later episodes are very hand-wavey and mystical, resorting to plugging plot holes with "God did it". Also, I prefer when atheists are represented sympathetically in fiction, as opposed to being wrong or the villains. "All powerful aliens and all mysteries converge to God" is a very tiring SF trope :(

Comment: I understand their goal and point and their budget constraints, but one of the biggest things that bugged me about the show was that it was essentially life on Earth today, but with a few spaceships and some robot bad guys.  And for a series that wanted to avoid cliche, it was rife with almost every sci-fi/action/thriller cliche known (except maybe time travel).  And the pervasive re-use of well known Earth tech without any disguise (can you say Humvees?) tended to break part of it for me. Don't get me wrong.  I did love the series, but leaving them all alone the entire series was a mistake.

Comment: @BBlake Which goes to show everyone's taste differs! I actually liked that the tech was (mostly) toned down and a lot like the tech from current Earth. For over-the-top futuristic stuff and aliens we have other shows... :)

Comment: @AndresF. but there is quite a break in that almost-like-earth-tech in the spaceships, in particular the jump technology. One would expect a society capable of creating a jump drive to also create more potent weapons.

Comment: In regards to the lack of animal life: There was an exodus from Kobol to the 12 colonies in the distant past. Logically, they had already mastered interstellar flight by then. Such a level of technology implies that they are also capable of lab-growing meat (or similar food-farming that forgoes the need for livestock). It's possible that the colonies never had animals on them, and the humans never brought any because they already had the tech to have food without needing livestock. Plants have a purpose, as they continuously provide an oxygen supply. Animals have little purpose if not for food

Answer (score 13):

Frankly, who is to say that there is not? The Lords of Kobol certainly fit the description of "intelligent life." WHile they are worshiped by the Colonials as "gods", from the technology that was shown it is clear that they were likely an extremely advanced race whose morphology was not the same as human beings.

Also, while the series does indicate that space is a vast place, its vastness is still underestimated by the writers. The distance between New Caprica, the Algae Planet, Kobol and the Cylon's empire might only be a few dozen parsecs. Outside of that area, dozens or hundreds of races could exist and simply no nothing of humans or Cylons or be so xenophobia that they have no interest in interacting with them.

Finally, it's clear that the Cylons are obsessed with humanity. They couldn't care less about space exploration or discovering other lifeforms as it does not fit in with their fixation on humanity. As for human beings, the core colonies were their home. WHile they built a series of highly functional societies within that sphere, in the re-imagined series (unlike the original) there seemed to be little interest in travel much beyond that area of space.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the reimagined series precisely for this reason. In the Original BSG, the very first episode involved sentient Bugs. But instead of going the rubber-forehead route, the New BSG focused on the human element, and told interesting stories about people.